# 95% confidence interval around sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

Suppose I have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$.  Suppose $X$ is normally distributed, and therefore I know how to compute a 95% confidence interval (CI) estimator for $X$.  Suppose that $Y$ is not normally distributed, but that I have an unbiased 95% CI estimator for $Y$.

Given that I know how to compute CIs for $X$ and $Y$ separately, how can I compute a 95% CI estimator for the quantity

$$W = a \cdot X + b \cdot Y,$$

where $a$ and $b$ are real constants?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then a CI for $W$ is straightforward.  But if there is any correlation, then you would need to quantify it in order to determine the standard error of $W$.

Comment: @heropup But what do you mean by straightforward?  There isn't any correlation, by the way, in the case I'm referring to.  Are you simply saying that I can compute the lower and upper bounds of the CIs for $X$ and $Y$, and then plug those into the equation above and directly compute lower and upper bounds for $W$?

Comment: Hmmm... on second thought, I'm not sure if you could do it without some kind of assumption of the sampling distribution for $Y$.  Typically, if $X$ and $Y$ are IID, then $W = aX + bY$ would have a CI whose point estimate is $a{\rm E}[X] + b{\rm E}[Y]$ and standard error $\sqrt{a^2 {\rm Var}[X] + b^2 {\rm Var}[Y]}$.  But the distribution of $W$ if $Y$ is unknown cannot be assumed in general.  The CIs don't add in the way you might think, because even if they are independent, there is missing information about the spread of $Y$.

Comment: @heropup Just to clarify, generally speaking, the CI around $W$ would be $\text{E}[W] \pm z \cdot \text{SE}_W$, where SE is the standard error as you have written, and where $z$ is an appropriate test statistic.  Is this correct?

Comment: I see what you mean, but you see the problem with that CI, right?  By using $z$ (which is not a test statistic but a critical value), You are making an implicit assumption about the sampling distribution of $W$.  You know that for $X$, this is normal, but since you don't know the sampling distribution of $Y$, you cannot assume you know the sampling distribution of $W$.

Comment: @heropup Right, yes, that makes sense.  I just wanted to clarify, to make sure I wasn't utterly confused :)

Comment: @heropup If I'm estimating $\text{E}[X]$ using $\bar{X}$, as the mean of normal random variables, then I have a sample variance $S^2_X$.  Do I have to divide this sample variance by $N^2$ before sticking it into the $\sqrt{a^2 \text{Var}[X] + b^2 \text{Var}[Y]}$ term to get the standard error for $W$?  I'm always confused about when I have to divide a sample variance by $N^2$ to get the standard error.